# how to set direction(rtl) for section3 in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Crystal Reports Multiple Columns Right-to-Left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910966/crystal-reports-multiple-columns-right-to-left)

I have 2 tables in section3. but when the tables are filling, at first the left side table is being filled, then the right side table .
but i want the right table to be filled in the beginning.
how should i merge this?
[image]