# Crystal Reports Multiple Columns Right-to-Left

Tags: crystal-reports, alignment

i wrote a program in C# win form. i have used crystal report. I want to set Crystal Reports Multiple Columns from Right-to-Left.

The following image.

[image]

Comment: select all the columns and press the left arrowkey

Comment: The following image? Am I missing something here

Comment: what you need ? Column alignment Right to left or columns Order ?

Answer (score 0):

Use cross-tab for this. you just assign left to right

For this use this link.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142064/Step-by-Step-Creation-of-Crystal-Report-using-its

Answer (score 0):

set a single column direction:
Right Click on IFieldObject (column) in section3(details): select "Format Object". Then you know what to do.
Good Luck!